# How come clicking on task bar icon to minimize window stops working

Tags: windows-10

On Windows 10 (and I think the last several versions of Windows), you can click on an application's icon on the task bar to minimize it.  I use this all the time, in fact, that's the primary way I minimize windows.

The feature works fine, and then all of a sudden it stops working.  Clicking on the icon no longer minimizes the application, it just does nothing at all.  So far, the only way I've been able to fix it is to reboot the machine.  I haven't really noticed any patterns as to *when* this stops working.  But it'll work for a few days, then stop until I reboot.

Anyone aware of this bug, and is there any fix or workaround for it?

**Update:** I found another way to fix it - kill the "explorer.exe" process and restart it.  Kinda a hassle though.

Comment: Have you checked your event viewer to see what's happening around the time the icons stop working? Have you updated drivers and run the various Windows repair DISM and SFC tools?

Comment: Nothing in the event log of interest, though I usually don't notice until minutes later.  I run the Dell SupportAssist program which keeps all the drivers and what not up to date..

Comment: Restarting Windows Explorer indeed works!

Comment: I'm having this problem in Windows 11 and restarting Windows Explorer doesn't fix it. I'm having to do it very often for *other* reasons (like invisible icons) but it's not working for this issue.